# Angular ui-router crashing browsers

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I have no idea what is wrong, but im assuming i have a loop running in the background of my code or that im routing incorrectly. But all i know is when i try to go to my index page, my entire browser is taken down, no errors or anything, just crashing. Any help would really be appreciated im just trying to move on from this problem.And in case this changes anything i am using a rails backend.

```
planoxApp.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home/nav.html',
    authenticate: true
  })
    .state('home.index', {       // our home page
      url: '/index',
      views: {
        "": {templateUrl: 'templates/home/home.html'},
        "assembly@index": { templateUrl: "templates/home/assembly.html" },
        "client@index": { templateUrl: "templates/home/client.html" },
        "photoplan@index": { templateUrl: "templates/home/home_photoplan.html" }
      },
      authenticate: true
    })
```

Here is the main routes causing problems, the home one is just a nav bar, and when you go to the home tab its supposed to take you to the index page, but no dice. Im not sure how much of my controller i should show, but here a small part.Its the parts that directly effect the routes.

```
app.run(function ($rootScope,$location, $localStorage){
    $localStorage.recent = ""
      $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
        console.log("working")
          recent.push($location.$$path);
      });
});


app.run(function ($rootScope, $state, AuthService) {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
      if (toState.authenticate && !AuthService.isAuthenticated()){
        // User isn’t authenticated
        console.log(AuthService.isAuthenticated())
        $state.transitionTo("login");
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });




  // GET request Area
  $http.get('client.JSON').success(function(data){
    $scope.clients = data;
  });
  $http.get('photoplan.JSON').success(function(data){
    $scope.photoplans = data;
    $scope.complete = true;
    // if(main.photoplans.plano_order_status === "Complete"){
    //   console.log()
    //   $scope.complete = true;
    // }else{
    //   $scope.complete = false;
    // }

  });
    $http.get('assembly.JSON').success(function(data){
      // main.assemblys = $filter('filter')(data, function(d){return d.employee_id == mainid});
      $scope.assemblys = data;
      console.log($scope.assemblys)
    });
    $http.get('employee.JSON').success(function(data){
      $scope.employees = data;
    });
}]);
```

This is the index page, and one of the nested views it has, all the views look roughly the same.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<!-- Main Section -->
    <div class="home no-subheader container">
      <div class="row" >

        <!-- left -->
        <section name="assembly-queue"  class="molding col-md-4" id="assembly">
          <div class="gutter"  >
            <div ui-view="assembly"> </div>
            </div>
          </section>

        <!-- <section name="employee-queue" ng-if="type === 'admin'" class="molding col-md-4" id="employee">
          <div class="gutter"  id="scrollArea">
            <div ui-view=".employee"></div>
          </div>
      </section> -->

        <!-- middle -->
        <section name="clients" class="molding col-md-4" id="clients">
          <div class="gutter"  >

        <div ui-view="client"> </div>

      </div>
      </section>

        <!-- right -->
        <section name="photoplans" class="molding col-md-4" id="photoplans">
          <div class="gutter"   >
        <div ui-view="photoplan"> </div>
      </div>
    </section>

      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This is the assembly page.

```
<div id="expanding" >
<div class="top row">
      <h2> Assembly Queue</h2>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left default" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" ng-model="searchassembly" class="form-control query" placeholder="Search Assembly Queue">
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <article class="assembly snippet row" ng-repeat="assembly in assemblys|filter:searchassembly" > 
    <div class="left col-xs-7" >
        <address>{{assembly.address_part1}},{{assembly.address_part2}}</address>
        <p class="timeline-data"> Due on {{assembly.date_due}}</p>
        <p class="timeline-data"> Job Type: {{assembly.job_type}}</p>
        <p class="timeline-data"> Delivery Type: {{assembly.delivery_type}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right col-xs-5 text-center">
        <div class="corner-ribbon" ng-click="open(assembly.id)" > </div>
        <button ng-if="assembly.new_order" class="btn btn-default" ui-sref="photoplans({ id : assembly.photoplan_id })" ><span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <button ng-if="assembly.new_order === false" class="btn btn-default" ui-sref="assign({address : assembly.address, realtor: assembly.realtor})" ><span class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
      </div> 
  </article>
```

If anyone has had similar issues or can see red flags in this please let me know, i am really stuck on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i actually found the answer myself, and im leaving the solution here for future people who might have this issue. But basically i need to have word of some kind in my home route, so instead of just /, i need /home. Because the browser was trying to load this #//index, and that was causing crashes. When using rails and angular together, make sure to have named routes to prevent this problem. Also make sure your nested views look like this, whatever@parent.child. Heres my new code.

```
planoxApp.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home/nav.html',
    authenticate: true
  })
    .state('home.index', {       // our home page
      url: '/index',
      views: {
        "": {templateUrl: 'templates/home/home.html'},
        "assembly@home.index": { templateUrl: "templates/home/assembly.html" },
        "client@home.index": { templateUrl: "templates/home/client.html" },
        "photoplan@home.index": { templateUrl: "templates/home/home_photoplan.html" }
      },
      authenticate: true
    })
```